# MKMapView doesn't zoom correctly while user tracking mode is MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I created a test project with few lines of code and with two components: `MKMapView` and `UIButton`. I ticked `mapView` option - `Shows user location`. Also I defined an action for the button, it zooms the map to user location.

Here is code from controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)changeRegion:(id)sender {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Pretty simple and straightforward, isn't it? But when I tap the button I see weird behaviour: map view zooms to specified region then returns back to original zoom. What's the problem? How can I keep zooming and track user location at the same time?

I notice similar behaviour with MKUserTrackingModeFollow tracking mode.

P.S. I forgot to mention that it's a problem mostly for iOS7

Comment: It happens on iOS 10 too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From apple documentation:

> Setting the tracking mode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow or
>   MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading causes the map view to center the
>   map on that location and begin tracking the user’s location. If the
>   map is zoomed out, the map view automatically zooms in on the user’s
>   location, effectively changing the current visible region.

If you want both to adjust the region and to track the user, I suggest you check for location updates and adjust zoom accordingly.

For example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT**

Instead of setting the region, try just setting the center,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

and let your button action set the zoom, keeping the same center:

```
- (IBAction)changeRegion:(id)sender {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.centerCoordinate, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

And very important: do not set your mapView to track user. Disable tracking user because now you are tracking it yourself. I think the default is `MKUserTrackingModeNone` .

Comment: I implemented delegate method `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` And it works somehow. But I am not really satisfied. Right after start, tapping on the button still doesn't work well. When I pan or zoom map beforehand, then button is starting to work correctly.

Comment: @Ossir This is because when you pan or zoom, you disable user tracking. Even though you accepted my answer, I edited to try to help you achieve what you want. Check the EDIT I made to the post. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I want to keep tracking user with standard map capacity (to show default icon on user location). Anyway, it's out of my question and example that I added works on simple case for me on device(not on simulator). So I continue investigation by myself=)

Comment: You can show icon on user location without tracking user. You only need to: [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES]; This will display blue dot on map, but will not follow the user. Cheers.

Comment: tracking user myself is very laggy and the heading/location jumps. I think apple is doing some internal work to guess about the next change. Is there a way to adjust the zoom when using the native tracking modes without resorting to custom tracking?

Comment: @yuf I have the exact same requirement.  5 years later.