# Tracking mode with MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a question about UserLocation e MapKit.

I would to follow the user location on the map (automatically moves the map if user location changes) If the user tap (or pan or pinch) the map I would to disable the 'follow mode' (like Apple map app)..

I tried this method:

```
[_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

This work well but I have some questions about it:

- Is possible to set a particular zoom level during the 'follow mode'?
- I noticed that if they are in 'follow mode' and I make a pinch the map, the 'follow mode' mode is not interrupted. If I still pinch the map (or pan) 'follow mode' is interrupted. I do not understand when you really stop this mode..

Comment: possible duplicate of [MKMapView doesn't zoom correctly while user tracking mode is MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518224/mkmapview-doesnt-zoom-correctly-while-user-tracking-mode-is-mkusertrackingmodef)

Answer (score 2):

I think i know your means, you can try it, in `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
func mapView(_mapView:MKMapView,didChangemode:MKUserTrackingMode,animated: Bool) {
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)
}
```

When you scroll or zoom a mapView the `MKUserTrackingMode` will change,
so you can reset it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the region or the center of the map to the user location in its delegate methods:

Region:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Center:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19518422/3601482

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to *reset* the tracking mode back to auto follow:

```
[_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

The question is *when* to reset. I would suggest

- adding a button (like the navigation arrow button from Apple Maps), so the user can decide when to go back to auto tracking
- or make a timer which resets on inactivity