# MKMap is not zooming when Map is in MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, zooming, mkusertrackingmode

I am facing a problem related to MKMapView.I set zoom level 17 on viewdidload but when in MKMap MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading  called  then it reset zoom level 14.I am unable to track where problem occurs.

Comment: Hope this reference will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518224/mkmapview-doesnt-zoom-correctly-while-user-tracking-mode-is-mkusertrackingmodef