# iOS - Map user location not centered

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I want a map to always be centered on the user location, but I want it to always be at an exact zoom level. What I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518224/mkmapview-doesnt-zoom-correctly-while-user-tracking-mode-is-mkusertrackingmodef) is that I can't use `userTrackingMode` without it zooming on user location.

So I created a workaround to follow the user's location

```
func updateRegion(withUserLocation userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: userLocation, span: MapBodyViewConstants.zoomLevel)
        // Avoid random spanning on the map by setting the region's span to be the same with the map's span
        region.span = mapView.region.span

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

The problem is that I get the location from `CLLocationManager` function `didUpdateLocations` and in `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` the `manager.location?.coordinate` differs from `locations.last?.coordinate`. It's a small difference, but there is still a difference( I should mention that I only get this difference with the wifi off).

Why is there a difference and which one should I use? After some research I got that `locations.last.coordinate` is the prefered one, but I'm not sure(and also I think the blue user dot uses the manager's location, but not sure about this one either)

One more question: What does iOS use to get the map user blue dot location? Is it the locationManager coordinates or what?

I hope the questions are clear enough...

EDIT: Also I think I should mention. The problem is not in `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation)`. That works fine. But at some point when I start the app I use the location from `CLLocationManager` and that's where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

The difference you see is normal due to how each is updated. You should always check the timestamp of your location object to ensues it is the most recent. Also, this is from the Apple Docs regarding `manager.location`:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this property may contain a more recent location object at launch time. Specifically, if significant location updates are running and your app is terminated, this property is updated with the most recent location data when your app is relaunched (and you create a new location manager object). This location data may be more recent than the last location event processed by your app.
>   It is always a good idea to check the timestamp of the location stored in this property. If the receiver is currently gathering location data, but the minimum distance filter is large, the returned location might be relatively old. If it is, you can stop the receiver and start it again to force an update.