# Retain map zoom level while there is a change in location

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

I am using a MKMapView application. but when zoom into the map to the current user location, the map zooms well. But when there is a change in current location, the map automatically zooms out to the original position where it all started. How can I retain the same level of zoom even when the location changes. Thank you.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    let latestlocation:CLLocation = locations[locations.count-1]
    let a = latestlocation.coordinate.latitude
    let b = latestlocation.coordinate.longitude
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: a, longitude: b)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}
```

Comment: post your code for didUpdateLocation method

Comment: func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
 let location = locations.last
 let  latestlocation:CLLocation = locations[locations.count-1]
 let a = latestlocation.coordinate.latitude
 let b = latestlocation.coordinate.longitude
 let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: a, longitude: b)
 let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05))
 self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
 mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
 self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

Comment: whr is the code?

Comment: let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)) this line will set region around the current location and will zoom to fix level.

Comment: that is the same in my code..so should i delete that code?

Comment: when i deleted that line from code, map is not showing current location.map is opening at some othe location .

Comment: Setting the tracking mode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow or MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading causes the map view to center the map on that location and begin tracking the user’s location. If the map is zoomed out, the map view automatically zooms in on the user’s location, effectively changing the current visible region.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MKMapView doesn't zoom correctly while user tracking mode is MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518224/mkmapview-doesnt-zoom-correctly-while-user-tracking-mode-is-mkusertrackingmodef)